# Why is Spring Roo giving me a "Member holding details required" error?

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I have tried running a few commands with Roo and it keeps returning:

```
roo> controller all --package com.package    
Member holding details required
```

Additionally, when creating new entities, it does not create the normal Roo aspects it previously created. Now it just creates a new empty class with a few @Roo annotations:

```
roo> entity --class com.package.Dummy
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/package/Dummy.java
```

Searching the web has turned up empty on this specific error.

Any ideas?

Comment: which version of Roo are you using?