# "Member details required" in Spring ROO shell

Tags: spring-roo

I have managed to get the ROO shell in to a state where it is unusable. It seems as I have the same problem as in [Why is Spring Roo giving me a "Member holding details required" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332273/why-is-spring-roo-giving-me-a-member-holding-details-required-error) but no help there.

When running the command:

```
controller all --package com.package
```

I get the following error message:

"Undo manage SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/i18n/application.properties
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Member details required"

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and I first got the error with ROO version 1.1.2, but same error occurs when upgrading to ROO 1.1.5.

Any ideas of what is causing this error?

Comment: Try performing a `clean` task with your Maven. It might help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try run 'development mode'.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?114893-quot-Member-details-required-quot-error

Answer (score -1):

This is a known bug. Please see the links in the related possible duplicate question.

[Why is Spring Roo giving me a "Member holding details required" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332273/why-is-spring-roo-giving-me-a-member-holding-details-required-error)